# Angular 8: How to use a Multi-Content-Projection / Multiple-Transclusion slot twice?

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

- I have an Angular 8.2 project that has two different display modes (landscape|portrait)
- And within each, there's a toolbar at top and at bottom, surrounding the main content.
- The `menu` as well as the main `content` is module specific, thus I am using slots. In other words: One out of 5 different possible parent component uses this component and provides the `main` content and an (individually different) `menu`, using [angular content projection](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/).

```js
    <ng-template #menu><ng-content select="[slot='menu']"></ng-content></ng-template>
    <ng-template #content><ng-content select="[slot='content']"></ng-content></ng-template>

    <section *ngIf="landscape">
        <div class="global-ui-top">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="menu"></ng-container> // 1st
        </div>
        <some-main-content>
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
        </some-main-content>
        <div class="global-ui-bottom">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="menu"></ng-container> // 2nd
        </div>
    </section>

    // portrait mode
    <section *ngIf="!landscape">
        ... pretty similar to above, also 2× menu, 1× content...
```

#### Problem: How can I use a slot twice?** No error comes up, if I use e.g...

```
A <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="menu"></ng-container> A
B <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="menu"></ng-container> B
```

...however the slot get's only "picked once" on last occasion (the tag between the two A's remains empty). In other words, my 1st `.global-ui-top` remains empty.

**nb:** This `ng-detour` in line 1+2 helps around a [certain bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22972). Is is not doing harm, but also not helping (sadly the `ng-template`-contents don't get frozen after “first fill” ). Apparently there is a [„uniqueness in the selection“ principle](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22972#issuecomment-375860258) regarding slots.

#### Is there a way to stuff the contents of the menu-slot into a template of whatever kind, and re-use it multiple times (all visible at the same time)?**

- perhaps a fancy flag on either `<ng-content>` or `<ng-template`? ("static"?!?)
- or first somehow whacking the slot's contents into a `@viewChild()` (in component.ts)...
- else...?

**minor update**

It seems possible to capture the ng-template reference into a View Child:

```
   @ViewChild('menu', {static: true}) menuA: TemplateRef<any>;
```

...a `console.dir()` shows me a valid ElementRef, but I don't manage to output that in the .html-Template, i.e. `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="menuA"></ng-template>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTwKhxLZ3jI&t=1s) is going to be useful.

My understanding is that `ng-content` does **not create** content, it simply moves content from one part to another.

I think the solution to your problem is to use `ng-template`. For example:

#### projected.component.ts

```js
let instances = 0;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projected',
template: `projected instance nr: {{ instanceId }}`
})
export class ProjectedComponent implements OnInit {
  instanceId: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.instanceId = ++instances;
  }

}
```

#### parent.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <h3>Parent component</h3>

    <p>Using content #1</p>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>

    <p>Using content #2</p>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild('content', { read: TemplateRef }) content: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And here's the important thing:

```html
<app-parent>
  <ng-template #content>
    <app-projected></app-projected>
  </ng-template>
</app-parent>
```

As far as I understand, what's inside an `ng-template` can be thought of as a blueprint. So every time you use `ng-template`, you'd create a *new instance* of that blueprint.

[Demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/lanUdMauw7oaHsdEF3wt?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: “doing the `ng-template` thing one level further up” — thank you, that indeed brilliantly solved it! Thanxs heaps!